# I can't upload an image to Flamelink

Tags: flamelink-cms

I'm trying to upload images to my Flamelink project from `Media` menu. I add images and click `UPLOAD`, then it shows `Upload cancelled: Tap to retry`. Why is this happening? The internet connection that I'm using has no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the very same problem and figured out that firebase storage was not setup correctly. Go to firebase console->storage->rules and then add your rules.
I use these rules (You can customize rules for flamelink resources and others):

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /flamelink/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```